# how to split characters into separate column stored in data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-cleaning

i have a dataset with many columns and i have below columns need to separate it as a new column, below are example of what a kind of dataset i have:

[image]

using python, my goal is to subset a character into separate column to have an abilities to working on numbers as the first 6 numbers after characters representing the date like ( 220519 ) 2022/05/19 and the same for other values,

so I expected my final output in data frame to be:

[image]

Comment: what exactly is in `y`? Is the first letter missing?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df[['y', 'z']] = df['x'].str.extract(r'(\D+)(\d{6})')
```

If you want to exclude the first letter in y, use:

```
df[['y', 'z']] = df['x'].str.extract(r'.(\D+)(\d{6})')
```